# Google Webmaster Tools error "Url blocked by robots.txt."

Tags: robots.txt, google-xml-sitemaps, customization

I have a WordPress website, I submitted it to Google Webmaster and after submitting the sitemap, it's giving me error "URL blocked by robots.txt".

Please help, what should I do?

Comment: Can you please specify what URL is being blocked? the entire website? a CSS file? or?

Comment: Go to Crawl - Robots.txt Tester and paste the results here please !

Answer (score 0):

Try to go Settings --> Reading, take a look if Search Engine Visibility is checked, and in this case unchecked. Now the robots.txt has disallow only wp-admin path

Comment: It's unchecked.

Comment: Read [link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35235?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

You can [read this article](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/crawl-error-url-restricted-by-robots-txt/).

Some from there:

> 1. This error appears when Google is unable to crawl the specific URL due to a robots.txt restriction.
> 2. Google is unable to crawl this URL for a variety of reasons. The following places may contain a statement that prevents crawling.
>
>    - <meta name=”robots” content=”noindex” />
>    - X-Robots-Tag: noindex
>    - Disallow: [Path Or / ] (in robots.txt. file)